# WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'upload_data_to_server' from module 'manual';

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm trying to document a Django project using Sphinx's autodoc extension. I have two main problems:

1. It's documenting excessivelly in some modules (importing documentation that I don't want from django)
2. It's not documenting one of the packages at all.

Here is my django tree:

```
|main_app
|   core
|      migrations
|      static
|      templates
|      consumers.py
|      forms.py
|      models.py
|      routing.py
|      serializers.py
|      urls.py
|      views.py
|   main_app
|      asgi.py
|      settings.py
|      urls.py
|      wsgi.py
|   manual
|      upload_data_to_server.py
|   manage.py
|   docs
|      _build
|      _static
|      _templates
|      conf.py
|      index.rst
|      make.bat
|      Makefile
```

The docs file is the one I created to host the files created by `sphinx-quickstart`. Then, I changed the `conf.py` file adding this lines:

```
import os
import sys
import django
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "main_app.settings")
django.setup()


extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx.ext.napoleon']
```

And I changed `index.rst` adding `modules`:

```
Welcome to yourProject's documentation!
====================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   modules


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

I executed `sphinx-apidoc -o . ..` and `./make html`. I get something similar to what I want, but as I said before, I get too many comments for django files, and no comments at all for the `manual` package.
I'm using this manual package for things outside of django, like uploading some data from some excel to a database on a server. So it does not follow django settings. But how can I specify this to sphinx? I get this error when `./make html`:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'upload_data_to_server' from module 'manual';
```

Do I need to add some new path into `conf.py`?

In the other hand, how can I 'clean' or edit the comments created by autodoc manually?

Comment: Make sure you have `__init__.py` in each of your directories to make it a Python package that Sphinx can import.

Comment: All of them have an `__init__.py`